# Consuming NFe webservice after updating the intermediate certificates

Tags: c#, azure, certificate

I return the error: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

How can I install the new certificate chain in azure? I tried to include the new string in the pfx file, but I did not succeed. When I request the consumption of the webservide of my machine, with the certificates installed locally, the problem does not occur.

The webservice address is:
https://www.svc.fazenda.gov.br/NfeStatusServico2/NfeStatusServico2.asmx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

I assumed that you are consuming your web service under Azure Web App. Based on my understanding, the azure web app could not trust the SSL certificate from `www.svc.fazenda.gov.br`. You could install your certificate to your web app as follows:

[image]

Then, you need to add an app setting named **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES** with its value set to the thumbprint of the certificate will make it accessible to your web application. More details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/).

Moreover, you could write your code and skip the SSL/TLS security checks as follows:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
```

**Note:** This is not a good practice, but you could do some additional custom checks (e.g. certificate name, hash, etc).